# java form for master detail data entry using database

Tags: java, crud, master-detail

In java awt I want to make a CRUD form for master detail data entry in oracle database. Gatepass master and Gatepass detail tables are joined on gatepass number using pk/fk relation.
This is form for gatepass. one gatepass receives multiple items.Format is like

Gatepass# 1                 Receiving Person:Mr.Tariq
Gate pass date:21-mar-2019

Detail
item id   item name   qty
12        wooden chair  4
13        wooden table  1

Can any one give some sample code.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, please read the following guidelines on [ask].

Comment: awt / swing canbe used

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than 10 entities and using Hibernate then you can try Desktop Java Forms which I hosted at: https://github.com/smart-flex/Djf

For example here is minimalistic definition from demo-application for two master-detail relationships:

```
<panel constraint="Center">
    <layout clazz="net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout">
        <param type="string" value="" />
        <param type="string" value="[0:0, grow 70, fill][0:0, grow 30, fill]" />
        <param type="string" value="[c, pref, fill] 15 [c, 150px] 10 [c, pref!]" />
    </layout>
    <items>
        <grid bindPref="st">
            <cols>
                <int bind="idStreet" title="ID" width="50" enabled="no"
                    noResize="yes" />
                <text bind="streetName" title="Street name" />
            </cols>
        </grid>
        <grid constraint="wrap">
            <cols>
                <text bind="st.buildings.buildingNumber" title="Number" tips="Building number"/>
            </cols>
        </grid>
        <grid noInfoColumn="true" bindPref="ct">
            <cols>
                <int bind="carId" title="ID" width="50" enabled="no"
                    noResize="yes" />
                <text bind="carName" title="Car name" enabled="no" />
            </cols>
        </grid>
        <grid noInfoColumn="true" constraint="wrap">
            <cols>
                <text bind="ct.modelList.modelName" title="Model name" enabled="no" />
            </cols>
        </grid>     
        <oper constraint="span 2"/>
    </items>
</panel>
```